# My PS3 won't stay turned on

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I just tried to turn on my PS3 and for some reason when I turned it on, it automatically turns back off, I have tried to turn it on 4 times now and it is doing the same thing.

Note: while I was playing Black Ops 2, the map "Hijacked" was loading and it just completely froze while it was loading.

Comment: Any beeps or lights flashing? If the light flashes yellow when it turns on that's...not good

Comment: Ok so I just tried to turn it on again and looked to see if there were any things that you said happened, and the beeping did... It beeped I thing 4-5 times and bling 4-5 times also, but when it blinked, it was green not yellow. @BenBrocka

Comment: Weird--sony has a list of flashing codes and that flashing green usually just means "i'm turning off". It should show a different LED code for an error https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1733/~/ps3-power-and-disc-indicator-lights

Comment: Ok, thank you, when I get home I will go to that website and check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the procedure found [on this page](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130208162649AAR2TXQ). Repeating the instructions here:

Hold down the power button until the PS3 turns off. Then hold the button down while it turns on. Hold it while you hear a first beep, a second beep, and a third beep. That will cause it to power off again.

Then hold the power button again through two single beeps and finally release it after a double beep. This will give a menu of safe mode options, some of which may help you resolve the issue. You'll need a USB attached controller to use, and some options may erase the data stored on the hard drive.

Comment: I actually fixed it last nite by unplugging it for about 10-15 minutes and plugged it back in and it worked. But I just posted another question, it states the other question I am having now.